# Restrict public access to server REST APIs without updating client app

Tags: php, api, rest, slim

I have created a public mobile app that use REST API (created with PHP Slim Framework).

I'd like to restrict public access to those API to only people that are using my app, in order to avoid people to getting the API url and pasting it into their browser to easily access my content, for example.

I have found some methods for authentication, but the problem is that my app is already public so if I set an authentication method on my server, then I have to edit my client app too, but people with old app versions could not access API so the app would be useless.

What is the best options I have in this case, to set restrictions to my API without editing the client app?

Thanks

Comment: Without updating the clients it is impossible to limit the usage of your API.

Comment: There is no way you can do that, except to force the client to download the new app which is updated with your authentication methods.

Answer (score 1):

You need something from your app that can be controllable from your api. Such as modal that shows a message that they need to download the new version to continue use.

The logic will be, when the Client app tries to access your Rest API server, check the version from the client app and reject it, then have a message to download latest app.

If you don't have this, the only way you can do is notify your users about the critical update in your application.